# jQuery Add Class if data value is true

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to a div by checking to see if the current class contains a `data-value` of `New`. But I'm not 100% sure if I am structuring this the *correct* way:

```
if ($(".link").data("value") === 'New') {
  $(this).addClass('new');
}
```

```html
<div class="link" data-value="New">
  <a href="">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Basically, if the `data-value` is `New` then add the `new` class to `link`

Not sure if that is correct or not.

Comment: What is the value of `this`?

Comment: @Taplar - Hmmm, it should be the link class...

Comment: One quick way to verify that is to log it to the console.  Always a good first step when debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `if` condition does not have the scope of the `.link` element, so `this` actually refers to the `window`.

To fix this you will need to select the `.link` element directly. Try this:

```js
if ($(".link").data("value") === 'New') {
  $('.link').addClass('new');
}
```

```css
.new {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-value="New">
  <a href="">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Also note that this will only work for a single instance of the `.link` class. You'll need to loop through each one individually if there are multiple elements with that class. Which you can do like this:

```js
$('.link').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data("value") === 'New') {
    $(this).addClass('new');
  }
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: #CC0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-value="New">
  <a href="">LINK</a>
</div>

<div class="link">
  <a href="">LINK</a>
</div>

<div class="link" data-value="New">
  <a href="">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Judging by the markup and the fact that the OP is trying to use `this`, showing them how to loop multiple `.link` elements might be beneficial.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I get it now. Yeah, so I'll have to see what I can do with that since their will be 3 will the same class but different data values.

Comment: Sure, I edited it with an example for you in that case

Comment: `$('.link').filter('[data-value="New"]').addClass('new')` could potentially work as well.

Comment: Awesome! This all makes sense now. Thanks!